# Printing a pointer causes a segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

In my program I have this two lines inside a function inside of a class:

```
    char* chunkToReturn = nullptr;
    std::cout << chunkToReturn << std::endl;
```

But when I run my program I get a segmentation fault in the 'cout' line,
Does that implies that the problem lays with the address of the class itself ?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: I overload the operator new, and I mallocated some memory from which I give a pointer to the new to return,  But then in a 'if' condition I give a nullptr for the new function to return instead of a non nullptr, and I get a segmentation fault when new tries to return the pointer, even though it should be possible to return a nullptr from the new function

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with using a variable of type `char*` which has been initialized to `nullptr`.

When you use

```
cout << chunkToReturn
```

`chunkToReturn` needs to be a null character terminated string. Since that is not true in  your case, your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to `char` is treated as a C-Style string and all characters are output until a nul is found.

The solution is to cast the pointer to `void *`:

```
std::cout << (void *) chunkToReturn << std::endl;
```